# Powershell replacing Character at postion 12 in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, replace, position, character

my problem is to replace in a CSV-File with around 3000 lines at position 12 character
" "  ( space ) with character ",". Seems to be a easy task, but I stuck. I tried this

Example of CVS File:

```
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000000,.......................
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000001,.......................
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000002,.......................
```

My try:

```
$filename = "File"
$temfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
Get-Content $filename |
Foreach($line in $filename )
{
   ($line.SubString(0,12) -replace " ",",") )
 } |
Add-Content $temfile
Remove-Item $filename
Move-Item $temfile $newfile
```

I will appreciate any helpful answer,
thanks in advance
Lightfoot

Comment: you want split the datetime into date and time right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you're piping [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) into [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2), a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2), instead of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2), the cmdlet. Then piping the result of the loop to [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2). This will result into a syntax error, pipes cannot be at the beginning or end of a language keyword.

There is also an issue with your replacement logic, a simple example:

```bash
'03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000000,..........'.SubString(0, 12) -replace ' ', ','
```

Will result in:

```bash
03,Aug,2022,
```

Which is clearly not what you wanted. This regex might do the what you're looking for: [`(?m)(?<=^.{11})\s`](https://regex101.com/r/XeIKzO/1).

For example given this *multi-line string*:

```bash
$string = @'
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000000,........
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000001,........
03 Aug 2022 00:00:00,212526237600000002,........
'@
```

The result would be:

```bash
PS ..\> $string -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{11})\s', ','

03 Aug 2022,00:00:00,212526237600000000,........
03 Aug 2022,00:00:00,212526237600000001,........
03 Aug 2022,00:00:00,212526237600000002,........
```

If you want to keep the white space after inserting the new comma, simply remove `\s` from the regex:

```bash
$string -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{11})', ','
```

As for how the code would look:

```bash
(Get-Content path\to\myfile.csv -Raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=^.{11})\s', ',' |
    Set-Content path\to\myNewFile.csv
```

Comment: Hi Santiago, many thanks for this fast, detailed and helpful answer!!!!
Will go through step by step to learn and understand how it workes.

Best wishes, Lightfoot

Comment: @Lightfoot my pleasure :) if it actually solves your problem remember you can accept the answer, it could be helpful for future readers. if it doesn't solve the problem comment here with the details

Comment: Hi Santiago, works perfect! This two "simple" lines of code will save hours of manual activity!  Will mark the question as answered. BW